# undefined function TYPO3\CMS\IndexedSearch\mb_strcut()

Tags: typo3

I'm trying to create a webpage using TYPO3 8.7, but when i go to Localhost/index.php it says "Oops an error has occured".

The only way i can see my webpage, is through the TYPO3 backend login apperently.

This is the error that it logs in the backend of TYPO3:
>

> Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Call to undefined >function TYPO3\CMS\IndexedSearch\mb_strcut() | Error thrown in file >/var/www/html/typo3_src-8.7.0/typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Classes/Indexer.php in >line 1314. Requested URL: Localhost/index.php

And my line 1314 is this:

> $bodyDescription = mb_strcut($bodyDescription, 0, $maxL, 'utf-8');

I'm very new to this. So far i've been able to sort all bugs with the help from these forums and others, but unfortunately I can't find any solution to this one.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Let me know if i need to provide some additionel information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error means that mbstring php extension is not enabled. You should install it, if you have Ubuntu you should execute

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

Read more about installation of this PHP extension [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php)

Answer (score 0):

Me, I received almost a similar error after updating my `PHP version` from `7.4` to `8.1` and my Laravel App version too to the latest version. The specific error in my case was `Call to undefined function mb_strcut()` in the mailer class.

To resolve this I tried to run the code

> sudo apt-get install php-mbstring

but that did not help my situation.

Since I had swapped my PHP version from `7.4` to `8.1` so I had to install the specific php-mbstring that corresponds to the PHP `version 8.1` as shown below:

> sudo apt-get install php8.1-mbstring

This worked for me. Hope it works for you too.